# Angular - Trouble injecting a factory into a controller

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, controller, factory

I'm trying to separate my angular code into factories, so my controllers don't become unmaintainable. Specifically, in my factory, I will house code that will be shared across multiple controllers.

The problem is, I cannot seem to inject a factory into my controller no matter what I do.

Here's my factory

```
angular.module('my-app')
    .factory('Game', function() {
        var colors = ['#FF0000', '#660000', '#FF3300', '#FF9900', '#003300',
                      '#000033', '#660033', '#FF0033', '#383838'];
    });
```

Here's my controller

```
angular.module('my-app')
    .controller('gamesController', ['$scope', '$interval', 'Game', 
    function($scope, $interval, Game) {
```

And here's my loading order

```
<script src='scripts/app.js'></script>
<script src='scripts/services/game.js'></script>
<script src='scripts/controllers/navController.js'></script>
<script src='scripts/controllers/gamesController.js'></script>
```

I get `undefined provider` and I cannot figure out where the problem is.

Comment: That's because your factory doesn't have any return value. Try `return { colors: ['#FF0000', '#660000', '#FF3300', '#FF9900', '#003300','#000033', '#660033', '#FF0033', '#383838'];}`

Comment: Factories have to have a return statement? I had no idea about that. Will test this out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular Factory must have a return result.

Syntax: module.factory( 'factoryName', function );

Result: When declaring factoryName as an injectable argument you will be provided with the value that is returned by invoking the function reference passed to module.factory.

your factory should be like this:

```
angular.module('my-app')
    .factory('Game', function() {
        return { colors : ['#FF0000', '#660000', '#FF3300', '#FF9900', '#003300',
                      '#000033', '#660033', '#FF0033', '#383838']
               }
    });
```

if you want to know more details, please visit [AngularJS: Service vs provider vs factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666048/angularjs-service-vs-provider-vs-factory)

Comment: This really helped me out a lot. Saved me a lot of headaches.